# Comparing dataset with array of data asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have this page of operators that has two tables with data from database, one table with existing operators and one table with existing users. If a user is already an operator, I want that row to be hidden in the table. Here is my code:

C#:

```
        var userDetailsList = new List<ContactPartial>();
        TellusAPI.TellusUserDetails userDetails;

        var operators = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId); //DataSet
        var getUser = webSearch.DoSearchForNameAndNumber(userId, txtSearchForOperator.Text, false, "", "", false, false, out userDetails); //Array

        if (getUser == null)
        {
            userDetailsList.Add(new ContactPartial(userDetails));
            rptAdd.DataSource = null;
        }

        else
        {
            var query = getUser.Where(y => y.ID == (long)operators.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]).Select(x => x.ID);

            var result = from o in operators.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                         where o.Field<int>("ID") == Convert.ToInt64(query)
                         select o;


            rptAdd.DataSource = result;
        }
```

Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for converting.
/// </summary>
public class ContactPartial
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ContactPartial(TellusUserDetails tud)
    {
        if (tud == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Id = tud.UserID;
        FirstName = tud.FirstName;
        LastName = tud.LastName;
        CompanyName = tud.Organisation.Description;
        Email = tud.Email;
    }

    public ContactPartial(TellusSearchUserInfo tsi)
    {
        if (tsi == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Id = tsi.ID;
        FirstName = tsi.FirstName;
        LastName = tsi.LastName;
        CompanyName = tsi.CompanyName;
        Email = tsi.Email;
    }
}
```

So I now compare these two and filter the rows with ID, but it still reads all rows. Why?

Comment: If you can, change the query. It's the best and simplest option.

Comment: @A.Chiesa please check the updated question.

Comment: `foreach (var Operator in userDetailsList)
            {
                if (!userDetailsList.Contains(Operator)) continue;
                dv.RowFilter = "ID = " + Operator.Id;
            }` This makes no sense. Operator will always be contained in userDetailsList - Operator is the variable generated by looping through UserDetailsList! Anyway, the same as the last question you asked, the simplest way to solve this is to change the underlying database queries, or create new ones. Learn how to do JOINs between your tables - it makes this kind of thing easy.

Comment: Could you please create a post and explain in code what you are saying?

Comment: @ADyson Read comment.

Comment: I can't create a complete answer post because I don't know your exact data structure underneath. Does the "operators" table has a "user_id" field in it? If so, you could get the data you need by doing something like `SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT o.user_id from operators)` That should give you all users who are not already mentioned in the operators table. So actually you don't need a JOIN for this, more like the opposite of a join. But anyway doing this will give you the dataset you want without having to manipulate it in C#

Comment: Yes, the Operators table has a userId that specifies the user in the user table. So I should just create a variable with your query and adding it to my list and therefore binding it to the repeater?

Comment: yes, that would be easiest. Much simpler than trying to combine 2 separate datasets after they have been retrieved from the database. Also it will perform better because you have 1 query instead of 2, and you have no looping in the C#

Comment: @ADyson The only problem is that one of the "datasources" is an Array of users, and not a DataSet. So how am I supposed to create a sql query with an array and dataset mixed together?

Comment: huh? A SQL query is done on your database. Long before it gets anywhere near C# with its arrays and datasets. You run the query, and then in C# that becomes one single dataset. Or one single array, or whatever you want, really. Just needs to be something to bind to your repeater. I understand that you need two lists - one with existing operators, and one with users who are not already operators. I'm suggesting you how to get the second one without having to mess about with your looping through all the objects and comparing them. One simple SQL query instead.

Comment: @ADyson I understand what you are saying, but I just dont know how to create a query like that. I tried this approach, and it seems close that to working, look at the updated question!

Comment: you're a developer but you don't know how to create a SQL query???

Comment: @ADyson Cmon man, instead of insulting, help me out. Create a post and show me what you mean. I know how to create a query in SQL Management Studio, but here in Visual Studio, it's a different story with LINQ, Lambda, ADO.NET etc.

Comment: Ok well, sorry, but it came across like you had no idea what I was talking about. You can write raw SQL in ADO.NET. You don't have to use Linq, unless your organisation's coding standards require it. If Linq is the way forward, there are lots of suggestions here https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Linq+NOT+IN+query&safe=active&* showing how to write the "NOT IN" style query using Linq

Comment: @ADyson Ok so I tried your way, I checked your hyperlink, and got an understanding of numerous posts, and I got this solution. Check updated question please!